# all combination of a complicated list

Tags: python, combinatorics

I want to find all possible combination of the following list:

```
data = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I know it looks a straightforward task and it can be achieved by something like the following code:

```
comb = [c for i in range(1, len(data)+1) for c in combinations(data, i)]
```

but what I want is actually a way to give each element of the list data two possibilities (`'a'` or `'-a'`).

An example of the combinations can be `['a','b']` , `['-a','b']`, `['a','b','-c']`, etc. 
without something like the following case of course  `['-a','a']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a generator function that takes a sequence and yields each possible combination of negations. Like this:

```
import itertools
def negations(seq):
    for prefixes in itertools.product(["", "-"], repeat=len(seq)):
        yield [prefix + value for prefix, value in zip(prefixes, seq)]

print list(negations(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

Result (whitespace modified for clarity):

```
[
    [ 'a',  'b',  'c'], 
    [ 'a',  'b', '-c'], 
    [ 'a', '-b',  'c'], 
    [ 'a', '-b', '-c'],
    ['-a',  'b',  'c'],
    ['-a',  'b', '-c'], 
    ['-a', '-b',  'c'], 
    ['-a', '-b', '-c']
]
```

You can integrate this into your existing code with something like

```
comb = [x for i in range(1, len(data)+1) for c in combinations(data, i) for x in negations(c)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the regular combinations generated, you can do a second pass to generate the ones with "negation."  I'd think of it like a binary number, with the number of elements in your list being the number of bits.  Count from 0b0000 to 0b1111 via 0b0001, 0b0010, etc., and wherever a bit is set, negate that element in the result.  This will produce 2^n combinations for each input combination of length n.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one-liner, but it can be hard to follow:

```
from itertools import product

comb = [sum(t, []) for t in product(*[([x], ['-' + x], []) for x in data])]
```

First map `data` to lists of what they can become in results. Then take `product*` to get all possibilities. Finally, flatten each combination with `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution basically has the same idea as [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665142/1071311). After you have produced the list of all combinations

```
comb = [c for i in range(1, len(data)+1) for c in combinations(data, i)]
```

you generate all possible positive/negative combinations for each element of `comb`. I do this by iterating though the total number of combinations, `2**(N-1)`, and treating it as a binary number, where each binary digit stands for the sign of one element. (E.g. a two-element list would have 4 possible combinations, 0 to 3, represented by `0b00 => (+,+)`, `0b01 => (-,+)`, `0b10 => (+,-)` and `0b11 => (-,-)`.)

```
def twocombinations(it):
    sign = lambda c, i: "-" if c & 2**i else ""
    l = list(it)

    if len(l) < 1:
        return

    # for each possible combination, make a tuple with the appropriate
    # sign before each element
    for c in range(2**(len(l) - 1)):
        yield tuple(sign(c, i) + el for i, el in enumerate(l))
```

Now we apply this function to every element of `comb` and flatten the resulting nested iterator:

```
l = itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(twocombinations, comb))
```